# Erro ao salvar a imagem do perfil do Facebook via PHP SDK

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook, libcurl, facebook-sdk

Boa tarde!

Estou usando a SDK do Facebook para login no meu site, eu consigo retornar os dados, incluindo o link da foto do perfil, mas não consigo salvar a imagem, ocorre o seguinte erro:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_put_contents(./imagens/perfil/**nome da imagem retornada**): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Para isso eu uso a biblioteca cURL com a função file_put_contents.

```
$imgUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/ID FACEBOOK/picture?width=300"; 
$imagename= basename($imgUrl);
if(file_exists('./'.$imagename)){continue;} 
$image = $this->curl->getImg($imgUrl); 
file_put_contents('./imagens/perfil/'.$imagename,$image);
```

**cURL:**

```
function getImg($url) {         
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'php';         
    $process = curl_init($url);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); //check here         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);         
    $return = curl_exec($process);         
    curl_close($process);         
    return $return;     
}
```

*OBS: Se usar esse mesmo código com a url de uma imagem de outro local funciona perfeitamente.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao trocar a função basename(), que buscava o nome da imagem por um nome a imagem foi salva corretamente.
ficando desta forma

```
$imgUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/ID FACEBOOK/picture?width=300"; 
$imagename = "foto_do_usuario.jpg"
if(file_exists('./'.$imagename)){continue;} 
$image = $this->curl->getImg($imgUrl); 
file_put_contents('./imagens/perfil/'.$imagename,$image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a seguinte hierarquia de arquivos:

```
/ (raiz do site ou projeto)
  pasta1
    arquivo1.php
  pasta_arquivos
    imagem
  arquivo2.php
```

Agora suponha que o arquivo1.php tenha o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php
require '../arquivo2.php';
```

E o arquivo2.php tem o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('./pasta_arquivos/imagem', 'vai funcionar?');
```

Se o arquivo1.php for executado será apresentado o erro de arquivo/diretorio não encontrado, pois o `./` será feito em relação ao arquivo1.php, e não em relação ao arquivo2.php(que funcionaria).

Esse problema pode ser resolvido com o uso da constante **DIR** (retorna o diretorio do arquivo que esta sendo incluido, seja por include ou require).
Então o conteudo de arquivo2.php sede ser alterado para:

```
<?php
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/pasta_arquivos/imagem', 'vai funcionar?');
```

Comment: Tentei fazer isso mas da o mesmo erro, como estou usando o Codeigniter também testei com **base_url()** e mesmo assim ocorre o erro.

Comment: Descobri mais ou menos como resolver, como mencionei no código estava usando **basename()** para retornar o nome da foto. o nome que retornava era _20228632_1500520143337391_4330092013544404463_n.jpg?oh=609e20c8b79053e75b7679d74c3b498c&oe=59FBE89D_, ao definir uma nome qualquer para imagem ela salvou corretamente